# How to write custom lexicographical comparator c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Lexicographical comparison means

if we have  strings "cat" "apple" "dog" "algorithms" after they are lexicographically compared with each other, they are arranged in dictionary order 
like following

> algorithms ,  apple  ,  cat ,   dog

I have written following comparator for sorting these strings in lexicographical order.

```
inline bool leq(int a1, int a2, int b1, int b2)
{
    return (a1 < b1 || a1 == b1 && a2 <= b2);
}

inline bool leq(int a1, int a2, int a3, int b1, int b2, int b3)
{
    return(a1 < b1 || a1 == b1 && leq(a2, a3, b2, b3));
}
```

Now I am  trying to introduce two additional symbols not belonging to alphabet set like 
"%" and "&" such that while sorting the strings(alphabet set)  "%" should be considered as smaller than all alphabets and "&" should be considered as larger than all alphabets that is

if I have

" apple% " and "apple&"  then apple% should be considered smaller than apple&

Can someone suggest me how to write this in c++. thank you

Comment: I can't follow you. What exactly are the 4/6 int arguments to your comparator? Are you comparing strings or not?

Comment: You say comparing strings, but you functions are actually comparing several integers. Why is that?

Answer (score 9):

There's an algorithm in the `<algorithm>` header that performs lexicographical comparisons, aptly named [`lexicographical_compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/). What's nice about it is the fact that you can supply your own comparison function, which can take your special characters into account:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool SpecialCharCompare(char lhs, char rhs) {
    // I'll leave the implementation of the '%', '&' special casing to you.
    // One way to do it would be to check if lhs/rhs are '%' or '&', in
    // which case, you can assign them to some other char value such as
    // ('a' - 1) or ('z' + 1).
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string s1("apple%");
    std::string s2("apple&");

    bool result = std::lexicographical_compare(
        s1.begin(), s1.end(),
        s2.begin(), s2.end(),
        SpecialCharCompare
    );

    if (result) {
        // s1 is less than s2
    } else {
        // s1 is NOT less than s2
    }

    return 0;
}
```